# how to hack mysql jdbc driver to change every sql to execute in program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

this is what i want to do, a little hard to explain.
in a special project (i want to hijack every sql executed).
In more detail, what I am doing is to analyze all slow sql in all tests written by our qa.

we have slow sql analyze tool which analyze db and list all slow sql passed to db (executed in any way).

But the problem is that i can't find which test case use the sql, as the sql itself doesn't  contain the info who create it. (there are tens of thousands of test cases, forget to refactor test case...)

what i am plan to do is write a java agent for  our test executer, when test run , our test executor knows which test is run and can put such info in java system property (no currency test execution in one java process , so no issue), the java agent will need to HACK jdbc to change all executed sql (executed in jdbc mysql driver in anyway...), the change is to add comment to sql so that it contains the test case info .
for example, original  sql is  "select c1 from db.tb" , will need to change it to "select /*test case XXX*/ c1 from db.tb", you can see that i only added comment to sql to link sql with test case.

the problem is that there can be so many different sql execution way, select/update, PreparedStamement, or non-PreparedStatement.

I need to find a common place (one may be not enough, but as least as possible), I prepare to use javasist  bytcode instrument wrapped in a  javaagent    to hack to change the sql. (get test info from system property and add comments in sql).

The problem is that I didn't find a good place to hack , anyone who is really good at jdbc/mysql jdbc implementation , please help.

thanks

Comment: anyone did similar things before, please share ?

Comment: write a library that captures it all, then add aop to all of the methods, and use that library

Comment: can't do it,  the existing test case are huge in hundreds of projects, used 1000+ dev/qa. i just can't change their project to change a library....  and only way need to be a hacking way.;..

Comment: which would be at least just as much trouble, since you would have to re-test the whole thing, and, most likely, quite illegal.

Comment: my department own the test executor, and we are in same company, legal is not an issue.  the main purpose is to analyze slow sql ,already found slow sql but just can't link with tests....  that's the issue and tooo much test case i can't change one by one...  so hack way need to do such analyze.  The ideal result is that sql in our slow sql analyze tool will have test case info on it.  and I plan to use such hacking way to do it, as there is no better way for me....

Comment: And check this on the database server? Provided not everybody is running under the same user, you can store what SQL is being run with what query and everything else you want.

Comment: Also the MySQL JDBC driver can be downloaded like a jar just like anything else. You can than decompile this and see if you can modify code and recompile it for your own needs (no guarantee this works because it might break the entire driver altogether).

Comment: jdbc driver can be recompiled, but the test project use mavent to auto use jdbc driver, i can't change the global mvn repository

Comment: we have technology to get every sql executed and analyze it , the problem is that you don't know where the sql come from... even username, client ip  etc.. just can't help

Comment: You can change the local repo and use your own recompiled driver. And the comment about that you don't know where the SQL is coming from makes me believe you are recycling login names to connect to the database. You seem very determined on going into a single direction and keep firing down everything else because 'our implementation doesn't allow it'. Even the suggestion of decompiling the JDBC driver (and thus hacking it like you wanted) isn't possible. Maybe figure out what you really want first.

Comment: @BenXu you are talking about hacking the MySQL driver ... do you own that?

Comment: @Fullslack.dev - No need to fret about decompiling the driver or the legality of hacking it. [This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-source.html) specifically mentions "build[ing] a customized version of Connector/J from source".

Comment: @GordThompson I don't fret about anything, besides the fact the OP isn't clear on what he wants and what he seems to want isn't fitting into his business use-case. Great though that you can build your own driver, however I highly doubt this is a solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: You may want to consider looking at something like [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy)